# Why does this port scanner code sometimes miss open ports?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to write a simple connect port scanner. I'm testing it against the first 10K ports at scanme.nmap.org. It should see ports 22, 80 and 9929. If I scan 1 - 10000 it finds 22 and 80, but doesn't see 9929. If I scan 9900 to 10000 first then 1-10000 (as in the example below) it sees 9929, but often doesn't see port 80 or 22.

I know I could try using WinPcap via a .NET wrapper and go lower level, but is there anyway to get a simple TCP connect port scanner working reliably without WinPcap?

Note: I currently do the scans in batches of 100 because I got even worse results if doing them in bigger chunks.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ps
{
internal class Program
{
    private const int batchSize = 100;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int minPort = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
        int maxPort = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);

        int loops;

        if (maxPort < batchSize)
        {
            loops = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            loops = maxPort/batchSize;
        }

        // If I look for 9929 in the inital 100 - I can find it
        Parallel.For(9900, 10000, port =>
                                      {
                                          string host = "scanme.nmap.org";
                                          bool res = TryConnect(host, port, 5000);

                                          if (res)
                                          {
                                              Console.WriteLine("\nConnected: " + port + "\n");
                                          }
                                      });

        // now loop through all ports in batches
        // should see 22, 80 & 9929 but normally doesn't
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            minPort = 1 + (i*batchSize);
            if (loops != 1)
            {
                maxPort = batchSize + (i*batchSize);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("minPort:" + minPort + " maxPort:" + maxPort);
            Parallel.For(minPort, maxPort, port =>
                                               {
                                                   string host = "scanme.nmap.org";
                                                   bool res = TryConnect(host, port, 5000);

                                                   if (res)
                                                   {
                                                       Console.WriteLine("\nConnected: " + port + "\n");
                                                   }
                                               });
        }

        // Can see port 22 and 80 still?
        Parallel.For(1, 100, port =>
                                 {
                                     string host = "scanme.nmap.org";
                                     bool res = TryConnect(host, port, 5000);

                                     if (res)
                                     {
                                         Console.WriteLine("\nConnected: " + port + "\n");
                                     }
                                 });
    }


    private static bool TryConnect(string strIpAddress, int intPort, int nTimeoutMsec)
    {
        Socket socket = null;
        bool retval = false;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(strIpAddress, intPort, null, null);
            bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(nTimeoutMsec, true);
            retval = socket.Connected;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error: " + intPort);
            retval = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != socket)
                socket.Close();
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried with a higher timeout ?

Comment: @sh4nx0r Just cranked it up to 15s - it saw 9929, but not 80 or 22.

Comment: @Andrew Barber All ports are being checked, it's just that it only reliably connects to ones in the first 100 checked. If I scan 1-100 first it always see 22 and 80. While if I scan 9900 to 10000 first it often misses 80 or 22, but not every time.

Comment: @FunLovinCoder, Sorry mate i really wanna test that code out, but am away from my PC right now. I have favourited your question btw., so when am back i will have a look if you still haven't found an answer.

Comment: Perhaps a firewall decides that it's an evil portscan™  and blocks it after the first few ports.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Interesting thought. However, when I try with nmap using -sT for connect it sees all 3 ports.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an off-by-one on calculating loops if it doesn't come out even.

Note how all your failures would have been in the last pass.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't explain why it sometimes misses the ports. The ones I'm interested in i.e., 22 80 and 9929 it always tries to connect to.

Comment: @FunLovinCoder: If the number of ports you try to scan isn't evenly divisible by your blocksize the ports in the partial block won't run and it won't even try.  The port numbers giving you trouble are always in that last block.

Comment: The ones giving me trouble are not all in the last block - 22 and 80 are in the first block I scan after 9900-10000. Your point is valid, but it is a red herring re the code missing these particular ports.